# What repo contains the json-taglib artifact?

Tags: json, maven, repository, jstl

I'm using Maven 3.1.1, Java 6, and JBoss 7.1.3.  I want to render objects on my JSP as JSON, but when I include this in my pom

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>json-taglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
                    <version>0.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

I get this notice ...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:66.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find json-taglib:json-taglib:jar:0.4.1 in https://repository-myrepo.forge.cloudbees.com/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cloudbees-private-release-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Is this artifact available in any public repo?  I want to avoid downloading the artifact or installing it to a repo that only I have access to.  Alternatively, if there is a publically accessible library that does the same thing, I'm fine to use that.

**Edit:** Set up my repository directive as per the answer given, but still getting an error

```
            <repository>
                    <id>atg-json-taglib</id>
                    <name>ATG JSON</name>
                    <url>http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
                    <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
            </repository>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should check this repository.

http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/atg/taglib/json/json-taglib/0.4.1/

You can add ths repository like this:

```
<repository>
  <id>public</id>
  <url>http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
</repository>
```

And add your dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>atg.taglib.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
   <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What do I put as the repository URL in the <repository> directive -- http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public ?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to show my repository directive.  I cut and pasted the URL as you have shown, but am still getting the error.

Comment: You should add like this http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/

Comment: Updated my answer with the URL you suggested, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this dependency as well

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.liveSense.scripting.jsp.taglib.jsonatg</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```